# Is there a real alternative on the Mac to Ctrl+Alt+Delete (not the "force quit" dialog)?

Tags: macos

Are there any real alternatives to force quit dialog on mac?

Alternative, just a command/app that kills every running app (not process)?

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're looking for, but would the Activity Monitor do what you are interested in?

Comment: Nope, because I will still need to use it, while the system hangs

Comment: What can Task Manager do that Activity Monitor and Force Quit can't?

Comment: Not specifically Task Manager, but the dialog with logout, shutdown, task manager etc.

Comment: My question is why is your system hanging so much that you need to do this at all?

Comment: Okay, to explain it in details i ran a script in terminal, which clicks on the screen at a specific co-ord every 0.25 seconds. I had it run in a while true loop, so it would never stop. I had no way to stop it, as I couldn't use my mouse and Force Quit's focus would be lost, so no way of doing that.

Comment: @Stephen, this is more appropriate as a comment on the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found how to accomplish what i want:

- Create spark applescript command doing `do shell script "sudo killall
  loginwindow"`
- Edit /etc/sudoers to allow doing above without password
  prompt: `Tyilo ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/killall`

Comment: You might also enable ssh - prompt or other iOS ssh tool will often still get into a mac that can't exec an AppleScript. Even when loginwindow and/or finder are non-responsive, the force quit keystrokes have priority to bring up the force quit floating dialog

Answer (score 0):

Here is a keyboard combo <kbd>**⌘ ⌥ ESC**</kbd> (Command-Option-ESC or Command-Alt-ESC) what bring in a small **Force quit** window.

but, when your script every 0.25 sec clicking somewhere, you will lose focus on ANY window.

You can for example try in another terminal window the following

```
seconds=20
script="name_of_the_script"
sleep $seconds ; killall "$script"
```

that small script will sleep 20 seconds, and after will kill all processes with the name "name_of_the_script".

Another variant is - rewrite you script for keypress check. For example, the next shell script will run until you press "q". Because you don't tell how you do "clicking" (via applescript? via iKey?) can't tell better solution.

```
#!/bin/bash

cnt=0
do_stuff() {
        let cnt++
        echo "Doing stuff here $cnt"
}

#MAIN LOOP
#set terminal into nonblocking mode
stty -icanon
key=''
while [[ "$key" != "q" ]]
do
        read key
        do_stuff
done

#resetting terminal into normal mode
stty sane
echo DONE
```